# Snapping control in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to use the snap control in my project. I saw a lot of examples on how to use it in openlayers 2. In my project I am using openlayers 3. Is there a snap control in openlayers 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It is marked as an open issue, https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1164. If you look at the source code for modifyinteraction and drawinteraction at https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/modifyinteraction.js and https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/drawinteraction.js you will see that some of the mechanics of snapping are in place already, but there is no snapping control. OL3 is still in beta (**edit**, gamma) and there is only a limited budget, so we will either have to wait, or write it yourself and issue a pull request on github :D.